# Mapping resource to jsp in Spring MVC 3.2.4

Tags: java, css, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a problem about mapping css, js, images to my jsp:
My project like this:

src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml

```
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.gif</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jpg</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml

```
  <mvc:annotation-driven />
 <mvc:resources mapping="/jsp/**" location="/jsp/" />
```

src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/css/style.css

src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/js/jquery-func.js

src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/images/sample.jpg

src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp

```
<head>
    <title>Shop Around</title>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='jsp/css/style.css' type='text/css' media='all'/>
    <script src='jsp/js/jquery-1.4.1.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='jsp/js/jquery.jcarousel.pack.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='jsp/js/jquery-func.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS and Javascript resources cannot be contained under WEB-INF, since files under WEB-INF are not accessible externally. As such, the browser will not be able to make requests to obtain them. Put them in folders directly under `webapp`.

Also, you shouldn't create `servlet-mapping`s for them.